# fwrite(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:140D00CF:SSL routines:SSL_write:protocol is shutdown

Tags: php, codeigniter

cannot send the email the error is  fwrite(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:140D00CF:SSL routines:SSL_write:protocol is shutdown
the code is given below

```
<?php
    $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
    $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://mail.test.org'; //change this
    $config['smtp_port'] = '465';
    $config['smtp_user']    = 'info@test.org'; //change this
    $config['smtp_pass']    = 'testtesttest'; //change this
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
    $config['newline'] = "\r\n"; //use double quotes to comply with RFC 822 standard
?>
```

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: fwrite(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:140D00CF:SSL routines:SSL_write:protocol is shutdown

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1846

Comment: have you solved this issue? If yes, please add your solution since I'm facing same issue.